# How can I prove that every complement of $C_m$ (cyclic graph on $m$ vertices) is a supergraph of every complement of $C_n$. For $m>n$ (or equal)?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I have found an "algorithm" that seems to work every time but to me it seems more of a "how to make every subgraph from this particular graph" rather than a rigorous proof.

I.e. to go from complement of $C_v$ to complement of $C_{v-1}$ you take a vertex, let's say $x$ and erase it along with all edges adjacent to it. Finally erase the edge joining vertices $x-1$ and $x+1$ (if labelled with the standard labelling).

Comment: What does "every complement" mean? Each graph has a single complement.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you are right.

If in a graph $\bar{C}_n$ remove, for example, vertex $v_n$ and
edge $v_{n-1}v_1$, then we get a graph $G\cong \bar{C}_{n-1}$.
(We denote the complement to a graph $\Gamma$ by the symbol $\bar{\Gamma}$)

In order to prove this we reason as follows. We have
$V(G)=\{v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}\}$.

The graph $G$ has no edges $v_1v_2,\ldots,v_{n-2}v_{n-1}$ and
$v_1v_{n-1}$ but it has all edges $v_iv_j$, $j\neq i+1$ and if $i=1$
then $j\neq n-1$. This means that $G\cong \bar{C}_{n-1}$.